# Comparing Sensitivity, Specificity, PPV and NPV of one test across two subgroups

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, method-comparison

I am seeking to compare the diagnostic performance of a test within a population with two defined subgroups.

I have the raw data & computed data, but am unsure what the best test is to compare the two.

**Group A:**

Sensitivity: 62.2% (95% CI 61.6%-62.7%)

Specificity: 98.1% (95% CI 98.0%-98.1%)

PPV: 35.6% (95% CI 35.1%-36.0%)

NPV: 99.3% (95% CI 99.3%-99.4%)

**Group B:**

Sensitivity: 63.6% (95% CI 34.6%-87.0%)

Specificity: 87.3% (95% CI 86.4%-88.2%)

PPV: 1.1% (95% CI 0.5%-2.1%)

NPV: 99.9% (95% CI 99.8%-100%)

Any help or advice is most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would you value in your diagnostic test? It looks like group A has a test that is a bit more trigger-happy, that is, eager to flag cases as positive, even at the expense of falsely indentifying negative cases as positive. Is this an acceptable tradeoff? // What about these groups do you want to compare and hypothesis test?

Comment: @Dave Forgive me if I am wrong, but I interpret this as group B as having the more trigger happy test. My interpretation: 1) both tests are about equal in terms of identifying the truly positive cases - they both identify about 63% of the actual positives (from amongst all positive cases in the real world); but 2) of 100 positive results from group/test A, 35 of these are actually positive (65 are false positives: PPV 35.6%), whereas with group/test B, only 1 of the positive tests is actually positive (99 are false positives: PPV: 1.1%).

Comment: I meant group B, yes. // That group B has slightly more sensitivity at the expense of lower specificity and considerably lower PPV strikes me as problematic, though you have more insight than I do into the costs of misdiagnoses and might have a convincing argument about why either could be acceptable. // Is your group B sensitivity confidence interval really that wide? // How do you calculate the confidence intervals? If you know the math, that’s great! If you only know the software function, that could be a starting point for determining the math.

Comment: Like @Dave, I am also curious to know what it is you would like to know about or compare in these tests. What is the test for? How serious are false positives and false negatives? What is the prevalence of the disease in the two populations? Presumably, it is very different because the PPV is so different in the two populations (much higher prevalence in the Group A population?).

Comment: Hi both. Thank you for your responses. So this is the same test but calculated on two different subpopulations, the null hypothesis being there should be no difference in performance across groups. The concern of excessive false-positive diagnosis has some relatively high consequence, and so I am seeking to quantify the degree to which there is a difference in performance across the subgroups. The difference is striking but I am hopeful of a comparative statistical test to quantify it better.